# How does the trap+missile part of a 3stacked missile spell work?

Tags: two-worlds-2

Is a **Missile+Trap+Missile** spell worth it?

I hadn't had the time to experiment with the trap carrier so far. Do they go off instantly in large crowds or is there a delay? Do they fire against single mobs at all?

Is it worth building a spell like this:

1. S1: missile/ricochet4/homing
2. S2: trap
3. S3: missile spray5/homing anti crowd spell?

**edited: **
removed most of the questions for clarity as requested by more experienced stackers

Comment: please don't ask multiple questions in 1 post.  Try to limit it to 1 question (or 1 main point).  If you have multiple questions its better to break them up.

Comment: So overflowing the stack with 9 separate questions is more welcome than this? Whatever makes the crowd happy I guess...

Comment: It just makes the question and subsequent answers hard to parse (by human eyes).  This is one of the big reasons, but there's others as well.  Plus, posting different questions in separate posts means you can get more rep! :)

Comment: vtcing since this is being broken up into separate questions so its no longer necessary.

Comment: Ok, done with the splitting and editing as requested

Comment: great job.  Hopefully someone who plays the game will answer them :)

Comment: Hopefully anybody still plays the game beside us. ^_^